# redirect https//domain1.nl/sub1/sub2 to https//domain2.de/sub1/sub2 with php or htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I need to redirect a URL f.e. https//domain1.nl/sub1/sub2 (from an old exprired ssl certificate) to a new active domain f.e. https//domain2.de/sub1/sub2 with a new and active ssl certificate with php or htaccess rules.

is this possible without getting an security warning from the browsers?

Greeting 
Jimbob

Answer (score 0):

Both of these require server to send redirect which happens *after* the certificate is validated. So no.